# Meta.filter_overrides for IntegerRangeField in django filter view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Using the example in the Django documentation for utilizing IntergerRangeField with Postgres backend to create ranges in "ages" with the following model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import IntegerRangeField
from psycopg2.extras import NumericRange

from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ages = IntegerRangeField()

    def __str__(self):  
        return self.name
```

This works perfectly however when using Django Rest Frameworks and using filter view with the following filter:

```
import django_filters
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from app import Event

class EventFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
ages = django_filters.NumericRangeFilter(queryset=Event.objects.all())
class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = ['name','ages']
```

the view generates an AssertionError at /api/event_filter/ and suggests adding an override to Meta.filters_override.
What I would really appreciate is an example based on the example model for this override, the example in django-filters documentation http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filterset.html#filter-overrides, isn't helping me understand how to get this to render.  I would appreciate any help with this so I can understand with this example to utilize this in the future.

Comment: Stack trace please?

Comment: AssertionError: AutoFilterSet resolved field 'ages' with 'exact' lookup to an unrecognized field type IntegerRangeField. Try adding an override to 'Meta.filter_overrides'. See: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ref/filterset.html#customise-filter-generation-with-filter-overrides

Comment: or in the browser view:

Comment: What's the URL you're hitting?

Comment: current url is localhost

Comment: problem is filter set, I cannot filter by ages without providing override so that django can serialize data in ages on filter view because IntegerRangeField is not a django field, the documentation explains the meta filter override I just don't understand the logic I need to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation, overriding custom option seems to be done inside the `Meta` class and not the way you have done it. 
`ages = django_filters.NumericRangeFilter(queryset=Event.objects.all())`

There are a few potential issues here:

1. The declaration itself does not seem supported
2. The overrides appear to be supported from within the Meta class
3. `queryset` is not a valid option for `NumericRangeFilter` AFAIk

Can you try the following:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import IntegerRangeField

class EventFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['name','ages']
        filter_overrides = {
             IntegerRangeField: {
                 'filter_class': django_filters.NumericRangeFilter,
             }
        }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this didn't resolve the issue I'm receiving the same error AutoFilterSet resolved field 'ages' with 'exact' lookup to an unrecognized field type IntegerRangeField. Try adding an override to 'Meta.filter_overrides'. See: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ref/filterset.html#customise-filter-generation-with-filter-overrides just to examine this is what the data for ages looks like on the api view: "ages": "{\"bounds\": \"[)\", \"lower\": \"19\", \"upper\": \"38\"}"

Comment: Have you tried simply removing all overrides and letting DjangoFilter default to whatever filter works?

Comment: I tried the code I suggested and it works perfectly for me; I setup a test Django project and verified it. You can clone it here and check for yourself: https://github.com/rtindru/interger_range_filter

Comment: I have cloned and installed your program, am I missing something the views in the browser are to these urls:^admin/
^events/$ [name='event-list']
^events\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='event-list']
^events/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='event-detail']
^events/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='event-detail']
^$ [name='api-root']
^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']      but there is an issue because no templates are created to render the views such as events/ is looking for rest_framework/horizontal/form.html I have created a template dir and will  look at it later.

Comment: Just the fact that `runserver` works is because of the code change mentioned above. If you remove the `filter_override ` from the code, runserver breaks with the same error you had. Try it

Comment: I will, I am certain you are correct, my issue is rendering to view I have your project will read more on setting router as you config in your sample project then attempt GET calls in postman to verify. thank you so much for going to the trouble of creating a debug application and everything.

Answer (score 1):

Working on a similar thing.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
import django_filters

class SkillFilter(django_filters.Filters):
    class Meta:
        model = Skill
        filter_overrides = {
            ArrayField: {
                'filter_class': django_filters.CharFilter,
                'extra': lambda f: {
                    'lookup_expr': 'icontains',
                },
            },
        }


class SkillType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Skill
        filterset_class = SkillFilter
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )
```

Then my model

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models


class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    skills = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True)
```

Doing this solves the problem, hopefully you can leverage on this to get a solution

Note: I think django_filters does not have support for an array filter that is why I used the `CharFilter` and this works for me

Comment: How does this work for a PointField? I am getting a similar error: unrecognized type for django-filter